# how automaticly access control to path url without using @preAuthorize and has permisson in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, permissions

I have permissions that each of them having one to one relation with customize controller method.
for example one method in controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user,'/getAllRoles')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Role> getAllRoles() {
   return (List<Role>) roleRepository.findAll();
}
```

Is there any way adding automaticaly permission that have same name controller function path and specefic configuration. for example with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in spring boot  and http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers, if i can use haspermisson may solve problem.

Comment: I can use hasRole in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for example: http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated(); how use hasPermisson in this situation.??

Comment: Read http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression